# How to use perlapi/ XS in an XSUB for array element insertion and removal

Tags: arrays, perl, xs

I would like to insert and remove elements into an existing Perl array passed into a XSUB.

`perlapi` has `av_push`, `av_pop`, `av_fetch`, `av_store` and friends for array manipulation. I was hoping for `av_insert` or `av_splice` or similar functions, but these don't seem to exist.

There is `av_delete`, but the documentation describes this as replacing the element with `undef`, not actually removing the item from the array.

Of course I could manually resize the array (av_extend) and loop moving elements (av_fetch/av_store).

Is there an existing API function I can use? If so a pointer to its documentation would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
void av_insert( pTHX_ AV * av, Size_t key, SV * sv ) {
#define av_insert( a, b, c ) av_insert( aTHX_ a, b, c )
   sv = newSVsv( sv );

   Size_t count = av_count( av );
   if ( key < count ) {
      av_extend( av, count );
      SV ** a = AvARRAY( av );
      memmove( a+key, a+key+1, sizeof( SV * ) * ( count - key ) );
      a[ key ] = sv;
   } else {
      *av_fetch( av, key, 1 ) = sv;
   }
}
```

Comment: That would crash if applied to a tied array.

Comment: @Dave Mitchell, If you post something better, I'll delete mine

Comment: @ikegami I was playing with your code snippet and found an error and learnt a few things:  1. extend line should be like: `av_extend(av, av_count(av));`.  2. I used the 'perl memcpy': `Move(a+key, a+key+1), count-key, SV *);` 3.  The direct assignment of `sv` into the array makes an alias and doesn't increase the refcount.  `newSVsv(sv)` fixes that?  I still need to look into what `pTHX_` is all about

Comment: @drclaw, Fixed. /// It's part of what allows multiple Perl interpreters to be in the same process. Threads use this. `pTHX_` is the parameter form, `aTHX_` is the arg form .`_` represents a comma. They expand to `PerlInterpreter *my_perl,` and `my_perl,` in Perls with support for multiple interpreters (those with `MULTIPLICITY` defined), and to nothing in those without. The context can be fetched by using `dTHX;`, but it's cheaper to use `#define PERL_NO_GET_CONTEXT` and to pass it as a parameter. Perl uses macros just like I did to pass it to the functions that need it (virtually all of them)